# how to free malloc inside failed realloc

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct person_st{
   char *first_name, *last_name;
   int id;
   Date birthday;  
}*pPerson, Person;
```

lets say i reallocate `sizeof(Person)*(++n)` few times.
inside each struct i also allocate space for the `first_name` and `last_name`.

assuming that at some point there will be allocation failure while i use `realloc`, what is the safest/smartest way to handle all the `first_name` and `last_name` allocations? its there still a way to free them after the realloctaion failure of the `Person` struct?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a failed realloc will not disturb the original data , so you can still refer to the old data (always assuming you kept the old pointer given that the failed realloc will return null)

Answer (score 6):

the best way to call realloc is something like this:

```
more_people = realloc(people, count * sizeof(Person));
if (!more_people) {
    // handle failure
} else {
    people = more_people;
}
```

This way you check the return code from realloc and safely handle the failure