# C free does not work inside nested mallocs and a realloc

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRING_LENGTH 50

typedef struct entry {
    char name[STRING_LENGTH];
} datum;

int main(void) {
    datum *entries = NULL;
    entries = (datum*) malloc(sizeof(datum)) ;
    char *buffer_ = (char*) malloc(1);
    free(buffer_);
    void *hz = realloc(entries , 2 * sizeof(datum));
    free(entries);

    return 0;
}
```

But if I compile this code and run the binary I get the following error:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00005572b0381010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bfb)[0x7ff4b3842bfb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76fc6)[0x7ff4b3848fc6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7780e)[0x7ff4b384980e]
./a.out(+0x799)[0x5572af4ca799]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7ff4b37f22e1]
./a.out(+0x63a)[0x5572af4ca63a]
======= Memory map: ========
5572af4ca000-5572af4cb000 r-xp 00000000 00:29 13267238517                a.out
5572af6ca000-5572af6cb000 r--p 00000000 00:29 13267238517                a.out
5572af6cb000-5572af6cc000 rw-p 00001000 00:29 13267238517                a.out
5572b0381000-5572b03a2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ff4ac000000-7ff4ac021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff4ac021000-7ff4b0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff4b35bb000-7ff4b35d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6815758                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff4b35d1000-7ff4b37d0000 ---p 00016000 08:01 6815758                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff4b37d0000-7ff4b37d1000 r--p 00015000 08:01 6815758                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff4b37d1000-7ff4b37d2000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 6815758                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ff4b37d2000-7ff4b3967000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6816376                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
7ff4b3967000-7ff4b3b67000 ---p 00195000 08:01 6816376                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
7ff4b3b67000-7ff4b3b6b000 r--p 00195000 08:01 6816376                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
7ff4b3b6b000-7ff4b3b6d000 rw-p 00199000 08:01 6816376                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
7ff4b3b6d000-7ff4b3b71000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff4b3b71000-7ff4b3b94000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6816210                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7ff4b3d6a000-7ff4b3d6c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff4b3d93000-7ff4b3d94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff4b3d94000-7ff4b3d95000 r--p 00023000 08:01 6816210                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7ff4b3d95000-7ff4b3d96000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 6816210                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7ff4b3d96000-7ff4b3d97000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd1bf9f000-7ffd1bfc0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd1bfdd000-7ffd1bfdf000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd1bfdf000-7ffd1bfe1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

If I delete the line (`char *buffer_ = (char*) malloc(1);`) and the next line `free(buffer_);` the binary works perfectly. If I replace the same two lines with an `printf("Hello");` I get the same error. If I replace `char name[..]` with double name it works, if I replace `char name[..]` with `long double` again it fails. This is very strange for me. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `entries` is (in some cases) invalid after calling `realloc` on it. You should free `hz`. But before you should verify that `realloc` have succeeded.

Comment: The proper way to call `realloc` is to save the result in a temp variable and check if it succeeded.  If it did succeed, you reassign the temp to the original variable.  If realloc failed, your original variable is still pointing to the original memory.  See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42079347/1212725

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all goes well, you should see `realloc` as a `malloc`, followed by a `memcpy`, followed by a `free`. So in particular if that `realloc` succeeds, your `entries` allocation is long gone when you do the `free`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that `realloc()` will reuse the memory that `entries` points to. While it's sometimes able reuse an existing allocation (particularly when you're reallocating to a *smaller* size), so that `hz == entries`, this is not necessarily the case, and you should never assume it.

As far as you're concerned, the memory pointed to by `entries` has been freed by `realloc()`, and the only valid memory is pointed to by `hz`.

The reason it fails when you do `(char*) malloc(1)` is probably because that allocates the memory after the previous allocation. Without that allocation, `realloc()` was able to grow the original allocation into that space. Similarly, calling `printf()` probably does some internal memory allocations, which prevents it from growing the allocation. Other minor changes also affect memory layout.