# Realloc an array and ordering an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, realloc

i'm working on C and my situation is this:
i have an array of struct, struct is made like this

```
typedef struct text{
  int index; //this index is a casual number that i get from the input
  char *string;
  char print;
}text;
```

and the array has a dynamic size.
In text.print (if a string has to be printed) i put this 'x' so it means if the struct contains 'x' i will print it.

In my main the array that contains those structs is called firstarray and i can access it with a simple for and everthing is working.

Not every string that is in firstarray[i].string has to be printed. Some struct does not have 'x' in firstarray[i].print.

So i wanted to copy only the structs with 'x' in an other array.
I tried like this (code below) but i feel that i'm doing something wrong even if it's working and i'm wasting a lot of space.
So first thing i will count all the 'x' that i have in the main array and do a realloc for the new array with it size equal to count.
i will call the new array secondarray and the struct will be the same.

```
//count is the number of 'x' that are in the array
secondarray=realloc(secondarray, count*sizeoff(text));
if(secondarray==NULL){
  printf("out of memory\n");
  return 1;
}
j=0;
for(i=0;i<Maxsizefirstarray;i++)
   if(firstarray[i].print=='x'){
      secondarray[j].string=strdup(firstarray[i].string);
      secondarray[j].index=firstarray[i].index;
      secondarray[j].print=firstarray[i].print;
      j++;
};
```

Now this process of creating the second array i will have to use it multiples times as in input i will keep having new structs to put in the first array and i will also have to delete some structs,
so the second array each time can be with a sizearrray higher or lower than the previous ones.
How can i keep changing the secondarray size and fill in new structs in a clean way? Do i have always to free the structs and then the array? isnt this a bad way? Thanks to everyone.
I also need to put the secondarray in order with the index i have in secondarray.index
for example if secondarray[0].index is equal to 2 and secondarray[1].index is equal to 1, i will have to print first secondarray[1].string and then i will have to print secondarray[0].string. Whats the best way to put the secondarray in index order?
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: instead of copying the entire structures to a new array, why not just create an array of their indices in `firstarray` every time?

Comment: could you elaborate? i think i didnt understand what you are advising me? Also if it may helps, i used to print directly from first array with the right order using a nested loop but the time complexity is too high. So im doing an other array to get a lower time complexity

Comment: I think what @Daniel Farrell is suggesting is to keep the actual `struct` instances that contain data separate from the array that holds a list of them. Then in the array just store something (a pointer or an index) that allows the actual data to be found. Then you can create as many arrays as you like, but there's only one set of `struct`s. Sorry if I've misunderstood.

Comment: There's a trade-off between efficiency and maintainability, no? Your implementation might not be memory efficient, but it's perfectly comprehensible. You could save a bit of memory by counting the number of `struct` instances you need to copy, before allocating memory. If you have huge heap of data, then it might be worth reorganizing for better efficiency.

Comment: @KevinBoone explained exactly what I was thinking.   I also want to add, trying to free a few bytes or a few k here or there by `realloc`ing your arrays when they're not quite full, is probably going to cost you more efficiency than it will gain.  Unless you're able to free many megabytes, just make sure you have enough memory in your array and only grow it, never shrink.

Comment: ok it might work, but how can i create this array in which i will put the index in order everytime? The secondarray size will change everytime and there will be new elements everytime so i'm not sure if i'm using the realloc in the right way. Thanks

Comment: When you call `realloc` save the result to a temporary variable in case it fails. It's good that you are checking the return value, but if realloc returns NULL, you don't have access to the original data in `secondarray`. Do it something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42079347/1212725